# unknown field 'ioctl' specified in initializer

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems, ioctl

I implement a simple example to study the usage of `ioctl` interface according to the book *LDD3*. When I compiling the codes, `unknown field 'ioctl' specified in initializer.` is reported.

I guess the difference of kernel version between *LDD3*'s and mine causes this error. I'm now using Debian 8 with kernel 3.18.14, which is much newer than the version 2.6 in *LDD3*.

I don't know how `ioctl`, or even `struct file_operations`, changed form 2.6 to 3.18, so please show me some reading materials to clarify it. Of course, besides the reading material, I actually need one solution to fix this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ioctl` has been renamed to `unlocked_ioctl`. E.g, see that article: http://lwn.net/Articles/115651/

Other operations from `struct file_operations`, mentioned in LDD3, haven't been changed.

Comment: Yes, it  helps me a lot. I am now using `unlocked_ioctl()` instead of `ioctl` in kernel 3.18, and it works fine. Thx.